# CSS3 transition using ng-show and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I'm developing a javascript app using angular, and for a fluid layout i'm using Bootstrap 3, i'm suffer a problem with the css3 transitions used by ng-show directive, i'm going to explain my problem, i have a jsfiddle to see my code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calamarico/mCPZc/2/embedded/result/)

I used the ng-mouseover directive on the "Options", then angular shows a submenu and i put the correct css for transitions (with opactity in this case) and i used ng-mouseleave on that submenu to hide.

The problem comes when i put the  of submenu in a .container (for grid layout using bootstrap), the animation, if you can see, is abnormal. If i take out the  submenu from the .container div the animation is correct. I don't know why i suffer this problem inside the grid layout of bootstrap, if anyone can give me some light.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top submenu" ng-show="isSubmenu" 
      data-ng-mouseleave="toggleSubmenu(false)" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <ul class="categories">
              <li data-ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-class` instead of `ng-show`.

CSS:

```
.fadeIn { transition: 1s ease-in-out opacity; opacity: 1; overflow: hidden; height: auto }
.fadeIn.hidden { opacity: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden }
```

HTML

```
<div class="fadeIn" ng-class="{ hidden: !subMenu }">faded in!</div>
```